# Linking 2 Linksys Wireless G Routers to have 2 separate networks

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, nat

I am creating a lab for a group of people and I want to perform a miniature netwars.

My plan is to have 2 wireless routers that the two teams can gain access to their respected router. How do I link the 2 routers together to be 2 separate networks? Do I need a crossover cable plugged into the 'internet' port on the back of the device? Do I need a third device between the two? Can you do this even though those devices perform NAT?

Ideally a person on one team should be able to ping a member of the opposite team. Each team would also have a DNS server, a webserver all virtualized. Is this kind of setup possible in any free virtualized system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, all Linksys routers support Auto-MDI/X which means you don't need a cross-over cable.

As far as what/how to hook to your "WAN" device to your routers... This needs more information to answer accurately.

Most ISPs (cable-modem/DSL/etc...) will only issue 1 public IP to 1 device... which means you can't simply attach a switch to the modem and plug in multiple routers.  (You can try... but I wouldn't get my hopes up).  Some cable-modems/DSL routers/etc can NAT the public IP, and have a built-in DHCP server that sits behind the NAT, and then all you need is to simply plug each device into a LAN port, or attach a switch to everything.

It is also possible to create a virtual-machine that would have an interface on the WAN device, and provide the NAT and private-addresses to the Linksys routers.

Possibilities are abundant... but information is on short supply.

Answer (score 1):

Linking and keeping two separate networks are mutually exclusive.  If you want two separate networks, then you just use two different routers.  If you link them together, then you get one big network, which seems to be what you want since you mention they should be able to ping each other.  In that case, you want to use one as a router, and configure the other as only an access point with the routing functions disabled, and connect them to each other using the regular lan ports.

Answer (score 1):

Can be accomplished a couple of different ways.  The easiest in my opinion is to connect the WAN ports to a common switch and set the WAN IPs on both so they are in the same network (i.e. RTR1 WAN 172.16.238.1 and RTR2 WAN 172.16.238.2) and set the internal networks on them to 192.168.X.1 where the X is either 1 or 2 depending on which RTR it is.  This will give you two separate networks and simulate traversing the internet.